# How can I force bash to deallocate a brace expanded variable without name?

Tags: bash, shell, memory, brace-expansion

For [benchmarking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153931/6958), I ran the command:

```
for i in {1..100000000}; do 
  echo "$i" line >> file
done
```

Bash [expanded the braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and stored the list `1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 100000000` in memory.

I thought this will somehow deallocated at a point. After all, it's a temporary variable. A couple of days have since passed and the `bash` process is still occupying 17.9GB of memory.

Can I force bash to clear these temporary variables? I cannot use `unset`, because I don't know the variable name. (obviously `unset i` doesn't help)

Of course, a solution is to close the shell and open a new one.

I also asked about this on the bash mailing list and got a helpful reply from *Chet Ramsey*:

> That's not a memory leak.  Malloc implementations need not release
>   memory back to the kernel; the bash malloc (and others) do so only
>   under limited circumstances.  Memory obtained from the kernel using
>   mmap or sbrk and kept in a cache by a malloc implementation doesn't
>   constitute a leak.  A leak is memory for which there is no longer a
>   handle, by the application or by malloc itself.
>
> malloc() is basically a cache between the application and the kernel.
>   It gets to decide when and how to give memory back to the kernel.

Comment: Also, for larger lists, use `for (( i=1 ; i<=100000000 ; i++ )) ; do`

Comment: Yes @choroba, I learned that (it's linked). Now I'm just curious if it's possible to tell bash to deallocate the variable.

Comment: Smells like a bug. I would report this to the bash maintainers.

Comment: i dont believe you have to close the shell, per se, but you might replace it. Maybe try : `exec ${0#-} $-`?

Comment: This is not an issue with `bash`, but with how operating systems handle memory allocation. Memory allocated to a process is typically not reclaimed by the OS, but kept by the process to be reused later, rather than constantly returning memory to and reallocating memory from the OS.

Comment: @patrick see the edit to my question for the reply from the bash-users mailinglist. It's actually not a bash issue at all. cheers

Comment: Completely unrelated: as a poor student still suffering with Sandybridge and 4 GB of RAM, I'm completely awed by nonchalantly having that amount of memory occupied but still use the system as normal, however commercial/server-specced the system is. Is this how poor people feel when they see rich people literally burning their money?

Comment: @Oxwivi student here too! But I have access to a machine used for CAE applications with 192 gib ram. It is, however, idle atm. Cheers!

Comment: Hahah, that's still pretty incredible. Keep up the good job "studying" on that system, mate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I did this thing in testing and, yeah, it consumes a lot of memory. I pointedly used a smaller number as well. I can imagine that `bash` hogging those resources for days on end could be a little irritating.

```
ps -Fp "$$"; : {1..10000000}; ps -Fp "$$"

UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 32601  4241  0  3957  3756   4 08:28 pts/1    00:00:00 bash -l
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 32601  4241 59 472722 1878712 4 08:28 pts/1   00:00:28 bash -l
```

As you can see, there is a significant impact on the process's consumed resources. Well, I'll try to clear that, but - as near as I can tell - it will require replacing the shell process with another.

First, I'll set a marker variable just to show it comes with me. Note: this is not `export`ed.

```
var='just
testing
'\''
this stuff
'\'''
```

Next I'll exec `$0`. This is the same kind of thing that long-running daemons must do occasionally to refresh their state. It makes sense here.

### FIRST METHOD: HERE-DOCUMENT

I'll use the current shell to build a heredoc input file-descriptor for the newly `exec`ed shell process that will contain all of the current shell's declared variables. Probably it can be done differently but I don't know all of the proper commandline switches for `bash`.

The new shell is invoked with the `-l`ogin switch - which will see to it that your `profile/rc` files are sourced per usual - and whatever other shell options are currently set and stored in the special shell parameter `$-`. If you feel `-l`ogin is not a correct way to go then using the `-i` switch instead should at least get the `rc` file run.

```
exec "${0#-}" "-l$-" 3<<ENV
$(set)
ENV
```

Ok. That only took a second. How did it work?

```
. /dev/fd/3 2>/dev/null
echo "$var"; ps -Fp "$$"

just
testing
'
this stuff
'
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 32601  4241 12  4054  3800   5 08:28 pts/1    00:00:29 bash -lhimBH
```

Just fine, as it would seem. `<&3` hangs on the new shell process's input until it is read - so I do so with `.` and source it. It will likely contain some default read-only variables which have already been set in the new shell by its `rc` files and etc and so there will be a few errors - but I dump that to `2>/dev/null`. After I do that, as you can see, I have all of the old shell process's variables here with me - to include my marker `$var`.

### SECOND METHOD: ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

After doing a google or two on the matter, I think this may be another way worth considering. I initially considered this, but *([apparently erroneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value))* discounted this option based on the belief that there was a kernel-enforced arbitrary length-limit to a single environment variable's value - something like *ARGLEN* or *LINEMAX* *(which likely will affect this)* but smaller for a single value. What I was correct about, though, is that an [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) call will not work when the total environment is too large. And so, I believe this should be preferred only in the case you can guarantee that your current environment is small enough to allow for an `exec` call.

In fact, this is different enough that I'll do it all again in one go.

```
ps -pF "$$"; : {1..10000000}; ps -pF "$$"

UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 26296  4241  0  3957  3788   3 14:28 pts/1    00:00:00 bash -l
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 26296  4241 38 472722 1878740 3 14:28 pts/1   00:00:11 bash -l
```

One thing I failed to do on the first go-round is migrate shell functions. Not counting keeping track of them yourself *(which is probably the best way)*, to the best of my knowledge there is no shell-portable way to do this. `bash` does allow for it, though, as `declare -f` works in much the same way for functions that `set` does for shell variables portably. To do this as well with the first method you need only add `; declare -f` to `set` in the here-document.

My marker variable will remain the same, but here's my marker function:

```
chk () {
    printf '###%s:###\n%s\n' \
        \$VAR "${var-NOT SET}" \
        PSINFO "$(ps -Fp $$)" \
        ENV\ LEN "$(env | wc -c)"
}
```

And so rather than feeding the new shell a file-descriptor, I will instead hand it two environment variables:

```
varstate=$(set) fnstate=$(declare -f) exec "${0#-}" "-l$-"
```

Ok. So I've just replaced the running shell, so now what?

```
chk
bash: chk: command not found
```

Of course. But...

```
{   echo '###EVAL/UNSET $FNSTATE###'
    eval "$fnstate"; unset fnstate
    chk
    echo '###EVAL/UNSET $VARSTATE###'
    eval "$varstate"; unset varstate
    chk
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
###EVAL/UNSET $FNSTATE###
###$VAR:###
NOT SET
###PSINFO:###
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 26296  4241 10  3991  3736   1 14:28 pts/1    00:00:12 bash -lhimBH
###ENV LEN:###
6813
###EVAL/UNSET $VARSTATE###
bash: BASHOPTS: readonly variable
bash: BASH_VERSINFO: readonly variable
bash: EUID: readonly variable
bash: PPID: readonly variable
bash: SHELLOPTS: readonly variable
bash: UID: readonly variable
###$VAR:###
just
testing
'
this stuff
'
###PSINFO:###
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mikeserv 26296  4241 10  4056  3772   1 14:28 pts/1    00:00:12 bash -lhimBH
###ENV LEN:###
2839
```

Comment: that is some mighty *kung-fu* you're capable of, sir. Thanks for the answer, I can test it only tomorrow.

Comment: alright, I tested it and it worked. The variable $var was preserved in `bash 4.3.24`, but **not** in `bash 4.1.2`. The memory was cleared in both versions.

Comment: @Sebastian - Weird, that - the version difference. It could be more reliably done with a `tmp` file as well. like `set >/tmp/state; exec ...; . /tmp/state`. It *should* work in any shell on a system with the `/dev/fd/[num]` links, but `bash`, unfortunately, as your own question can testify, often subtly does the unexpected.

Comment: you are right, using the temp file in bash version 4.1.2 preserves `$var`.

Comment: @Sebastian - if you would humor me - I wonder - in the older version - what of `command exec ... 3<<ENV...`? Do you still lose `$var`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, does the edit of the comment answer your question?

Comment: @Sebastian - no, I got that the tmp file would work, but I was curious if perhaps the here document might as well if the shell's parser saw `command` first rather than `exec`.

Comment: yes, running `command exec ${0#-} -l$- 3<<ENV ... ` will lose `$var`.

Comment: @Sebastian - dang... thanks for trying though. The older version must be dropping `3<` or else its `exec` doesn't properly interpret the `3<<` redirection. You're a pretty good sport, you know that? In any case, I am pleased that you found the solution to your liking. If you ever find yourself writing a `while :` loop into a shell script which you intend to run indefinitely, maybe remember this and instead consider how you might arrange to have the script more robustly refresh its state with `exec $0` at a reasonable interval.

Comment: @Sebastian - I think the second method described in my update would work for either `bash` version.

Answer (score 0):

No. Bash will never return memory it allocates for any purpose to the operating system. (But please correct me if I'm wrong.)

However, bash will re-use the memory for other purposes if necessary, and if not, the kernel will swap it out, so it won't actually be in RAM.

Comment: I don't have swap, so it _is_ using RAM.