# Storing longer text output in memory in shell variables vs Writing to disk

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, db2

I have the below call to db2 database command line tool inside a loop, which runs 100k iterations.

(the output from db2 is 5 rows of 20 chars approx per each call, total of approx 100k calls. The input to SP is prefixed to the output line from the SP and dumped to a log file.)

```
while read line
do
    db2 -x "call stored_procedure_XYZ($line)" |sed "s/^/$line/" >>log_file.txt
done<$infile
```

I am trying to make the whole thing run faster by taking out the sed and disk write from inside the loop. Is it advisable to store all the output in a variable, and later modify and write it to the disk?

What would be the length the shell variable can hold?

(bash, aix 6.1)

Comment: If all you are doing is appending output to a file what is the point of putting it all in a variable first? What else are you doing with the data?

Comment: I am thinking writing to disk only once after the loop gets over might improve performance, instead of writing multiple times inside the loop

Comment: Do you finish processing the data within an iteration, or do you need to process it further after the loop?

Comment: @dbza You should try it yourself. Whether it will make a difference really depends on how slow your disk is. Another thing you can do is move the redirection outside the loop, as long as your loop doesn't output anything else.

Comment: @jw013 Yeah I will try, but will the shell variable have a limit for characters? Can it hold all data the file could hold?

Comment: @muru There is other stuff outside the loop, but in this context all i need to do is prefix the loop counter to the db2 output and write db2 output to a file.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value if you can shift processing from outside the loop to inside it, you might be gain performance from holding off on the file, without significant increase in memory usage.

Comment: @dbza Maximum size probably will not matter. As far as disk I/O goes, buffering more than a few megabytes is probably not going to improve performance. Even if a shell has an unlimited variable size, at some point you are going to run out of memory, and your kernel is going to start swapping, at which point you've probably already lost any performance benefits you might have gained.

Comment: maybe im misreading, but if your plan to increase performance involves replacing `sed` with a shell loop then that is the *wrong* way to go. it looks like you're calling `sed` singly already for each iteration of a loop - that's where you get the loop counter value? for big jobs you should be using some stream capable tool - like `sed` to tell the *shell* what to do - not vice versa. `<infile cmd | cmd | cmd | cmd >outfile'. 10 to 1 thr shell is the weakest link in your performance chain.

Comment: Can you just have `nl` do the `call stored...` part with its `-s`eparator string. It's not very clear what you're doing though - you provide no sample input or output. What does `db2` do... *why*?

Comment: @mikeserv `db2` appears to be some sort of IBM database command line utility. It is highly unlikely that `nl` does anything close to what it does.

Comment: @dbza Since you have edited your question to show the entire loop, I would recommend moving `>>log_file.txt` outside the loop, so you have `done<infile >>log_file.txt` as the last line instead. That way you keep the file open and avoid reopening and reclosing it each iteration. If you want to try anything more complicated though, you should first take measurements to see if disk I/O is really taking enough time to be worth optimizing. You can probably do this by replacing `>>log_file.txt` with `>/dev/null` to get rid of disk I/O altogether and see how much of a speed-up you get.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks ! i'll try that. You can add an answer as well since this is what I was looking at

Comment: @jw013 i guess you meant  done<infile >log_file.txt  and not >> to append

Answer (score 5):

Bash variable size is not fixed.It is very likely hold arbitrary amounts of data as long as malloc can find sufficient memory and contiguous address space.Let's assume you stored large large amount of data in your variable.When you try to write data to your file,possibly you will get error something like that

```
/bin/echo ${LARGE_DATA} >> ${YourFile}    
/bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

This error related to max length of your command argument.
Please check **Limits on size of arguments and environment** section which stated in
execve man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html

"...
   *the memory used to store the
       environment and argument strings was limited to 32 pages (defined by
       the kernel constant MAX_ARG_PAGES).  On architectures with a 4-kB
       page size, this yields a maximum size of 128 kB*
...
"

**EDIT:**

Please also note that the above error for /bin/echo is just an example, it is possible to get a similar error, when you try other ways while writing a file.It is about argument size.

**SUGGESTION:**

If we think writing to file operations atomically, each time pipe is generated for writing, file descriptors are opened and closed.It takes a some time.Instead of using /bin/echo or others, you can write your own "WriteFile" program with higher level language like C/C++.What you need to is I/O redirection.

1. Open file descriptor
2. Write data
3. Close file descriptor
4. Optimize your code
5. Done

   Please check System Calls like
   **ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);**

   http://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Comment: that's an excellent point - I've run into that before in tests. it gets to the point where only shell builtins run because the kernel cant load another executable - you end up dead in the water.

Comment: The argument list too long problem can easily be bypassed. It's not really worth mentioning here. Who would use `/bin/echo` when nearly every shell has a built-in version?

Comment: @jw013 - how do you do it then? This isn't about `/bin/echo` - it's about `/bin/everything` - the environment gets *full*. If you know how to do it I'd like to know. I ran into it doing tests for [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154785/how-can-i-force-bash-to-deallocate-a-brace-expanded-variable-without-name/154840#154840) and took much of what I know about it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value). What else can you do when you can't exec? And what good is a shell in that case anyway?

Comment: @mikeserv If the goal is simply to  get the contents of a shell variable into a file, you don't need to use `exec()` functions at all. If the shell does something natively without calling any exec function, there is no argument list at all. There is no reason to try to put this shell variable into the environment.

Comment: @jw013 - I don't think I do misunderstand - my point is the shell's pretty bad at that stuff. That's why all of those other tools are there. It's good for the in-between things - the setup and teardown - but it's not the main-show. Its whole purpose is execing - it is only a *shell* for other commands. Why would you cripple it? Let it parse args - it's great at that - don't overrun its arg buffers. What does it do natively of any consequence that doesn't require an exec?

Comment: @mikeserv Ok you've lost me. All I thought we were trying to do is put the contents of a shell variable into a file. The answer I am commenting on is suggesting `/bin/echo ${VARIABLE} >> file`, and I am saying that there is no reason to use `/bin/echo` over a shell built-in. What are you trying to do?

Comment: By my understanding of the question, this "answer" is mostly off-topic and irrelevant. The first sentence gives a rough "probable" answer which I already mentioned in a comment, and the rest of it proceeds to veer off-topic into explaining why a dumb command that nobody would want to run anyways may not work.

Comment: @mikeserv Well obviously everything stops working if you exhaust the memory in the machine. That's why I was making the assumption that wouldn't happen. It is only about 10 MB (100k iterations * 100 chars) of data after all and everyone has 10 MB nowadays. The problem isn't running out of memory. And as I explained, you don't need to put this 10 MB shell variable in any argument lists or environments. So what exactly do you think you are running out of? We aren't passing this 10 MB shell variable to `db2` if that is what you are thinking because the question doesn't say that at all.

Comment: @mikeserv *A single 8MB **env** var* - and this is where you keep getting stuck. Who said anything about environment variables? Where in the question do you see OP trying to put this variable into the environment? Need I remind you of the difference between an unexported shell variable and an environment variable?

Comment: @mikeserv I'm sorry, that is not the case. You can see this yourself: `foo='not in the environment'; envfoo='in the environment'; export envfoo; env | grep foo=` and see what you can get. Only the exported variable is shown. I've looked at your links and nothing in them contradicts this.

Comment: @jw013 - it seems like I remember differently, but maybe I was `export`ing before. You're right - and this holds it up: `var=$(dd bs=8M count=1 </dev/zero| tr \\0 .); cat`. Thanks for keeping at it - I can be stubborn. That said, the whole 100k loop output *(not to mention doing it there)* in a shell variable thing is still an awful idea, I think.

Comment: @jw013 could you check http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/12586

Comment: @jw013 I referred to execve man page so the others have similar limitations, I didn^t say it is because of execve limitation.Hope I helped clarifying my answer.

Comment: @jw013 I suggested a solution to the problem(I know the suggestion is off-topic), because/but keeping 8MB or whatever amount of data in a variable is not right thing to do.You need stream the data in any moment the data arrived/generated.

Comment: @CuneyitKiris That is an interesting link and quite a long one. Would you care to elaborate as to why you want me to look at it? Like I said, your answer not really address the question at all. There is nothing to put in the environment or argument list here. I don't see how your suggestion of "write a C program that writes data" is relevant or helpful.

Comment: @jw013 u need to give the variable a built-in function as a parameter (can be any built-in  echo,xargs, sed etc.) to write a file (correct me if im wrong ,otherwise please explain ) . All the the commands has own max param size ,almots all of them allocate memory to keep the arg data.so how streaming cannot be the solution (which u can handle with small C code)  instead of using such commands ?